# Correlation reverses when deflated by the same amount

Tags: correlation

Assume that we have two variables, $a_{i}$ and $b_{i},$measured
across individuals $i.$ They have a strong, positive correlation,
say $corr(a_{i},b_{i})\approx0.9$.  Now, there is a another variable,
$c_{i}$ , which varies across individuals.  Note also that
$$
0<a_{i}\leq b_{i}\leq c_{i}
$$

We compute, then, for
each individual:
$$
A_{i}=\frac{a_{i}}{c_{i}}
$$
and
$$
B_{i}=\frac{b_{i}}{c_{i}}
$$

We notice that $corr(A_{i},B_{i})$ becomes strongly negative! This
is a bit perplexing, but the only reasonable explanation I can come
up with is this- across individuals, when $b_{i}$ increases, although
$a_{i}$ increases, $c_{i}$ increases by more than $a_{i}$ increases
on average, rendering this correlation negative. Is this reasoning
correct? Is there perhaps a formal condition linking $a,b$ and $c$
which can capture the essence of this reverse in correlation?

Comment: The nature of the answers may vary depending on what you assume about the signs of these variables.  The context hints that all of them are non-negative: is this the case or not?

Comment: Yes indeed, they are! Well observed..

Comment: I have included the requisite  information in the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen when the $c_i$ are positively correlated with $a_i+b_i.$  The geometry of the $(a_i,b_i)$ scatterplot reveals that such behavior should not be surprising.

---

Without any loss of generality we may scale all the $a_i$ by some positive value, all the $b_i$ by some other positive value, and all the $c_i$ by yet a third positive value, without changing any of the conditions.

Thus, it's no restriction to imagine the $(a_i,b_i)$ scatterplot takes on a classic "cigar" shape, with its axis oriented around 45 degrees.

**The rescaling by the $c_i$ moves each point to another one on the line connecting it to the origin.**  Thus, we need to envision a situation in which the points in the original cigar can be moved in this way to fall along a cigar-shaped cloud that is oriented *negatively.*  This is easily done: pick any nonzero number $\mu$ and for each point $i$ set

> $$c_i \approx (a_i + b_i)/\mu.$$

The projected point

$$\left(\frac{a_i}{c_i},\frac{b_i}{c_i}\right) = \mu\left(\frac{a_i}{a_i+b_i},\frac{b_i}{a_i+b_i}\right)$$

will lie close to the line $a_i+b_i=\mu,$ *which has negative slope.*  Thus, you can achieve any negative correlation, even $-1.0$ exactly, by varying the closeness of the approximation.  The value $\mu\sqrt{2}$ will be the typical distance between the new points and the line $b = -a.$

**Here is an example to illustrate.**  The $n=30$ original points with correlation coefficient $0.9$ are plotted as open circles.  Arrows project them to new solid red points with correlation coefficient $-0.8.$  Those points all lie near the line $a+b \approx 5.57$ (the median of all the $a$ and $b$ coordinates).

[image: Figure]

Comment: What an answer!! I'll be sure to go over it carefully. You, sir, should write a textbook on Statistics.

Comment: Just to clarify- a silly follow up I had- given that a_i and b_i are both scaled by the same amount, c_i, why does c_i not cancel out on both sides? I would imagine it would in the case where a_i and b_I are perfectly correlated...

Comment: It *does* cancel: the slope of the line of projection (that is, of any arrow) is $b_i/a_i = (b_i/c_i)/(a_i/c_i).$

Comment: Indeed- however, it seems it is not true when there is a constant. I am posting another question to that effect, and would appreciate your insight!

Comment: A basic property of correlation is that constant scaling of either variable doesn't change the correlation: see the initial remarks in this answer.